# Redirecting the content of a file to the command "echo"

Tags: shell, io-redirection, echo

I have a file named `my_file.txt` whose content is just the string `Hello`. How could I redirect its content to the command `echo`?

I know I have the commands `less`, `cat`, `more`... but I need to do it with `echo`.

I tried this:

```
$ cat my_file.txt | echo
```

and also this:

```
$ echo < my_file.txt
```

But in both cases it appears only a blank in the stdout, not the content of my_file.txt.

How could I do that?

Comment: Why do you insist on using `echo`?

Comment: @Kevin, presumably eventually he wants to expand the ANSI C escape sequences (`\n`, `b`...) in the file, which would be a valid usage of `echo` (at least a standard `echo`). Or presumably he wants to understand why it doesn't work that way. In any case, no reason to downvote IMO.

Comment: I came here because I was curious about why it doesn't work when I do echo < file.txt. Seems a reasonable question to have at SE, the answer was very helpful. +1 from me.

Comment: I have a use case for this. It looks to me like `echo` and `printf` don't handle `stdin`, unfortunately, that's why I'm looking, but I've got some text output from a command chain with embedded `"\n"` characters and I'd like to just print it properly. Is it so hard to imagine a use case where someone wants to print text to console?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can redirect all you want to  `echo` but it won't do anything with it. `echo` doesn't read its standard input. All it does is write to standard output its *arguments* separated by a space character and terminated by a newline character (and with some `echo` implementations with some escape sequences in them expanded and/or arguments starting with `-` possibly treated as options).

If you want `echo` to display the content of a file, you have to pass that content as an argument to `echo`. Something like:

```
echo "$(cat my_file.txt)"
```

Note that `$(...)` strips the trailing newline character**s** from the output of that `cat` command, and `echo` adds **one** back.

Also note that except with `zsh`, you can't pass NUL characters in the arguments of a command, so that above will typically not work with binary files. `yash` will also remove bytes that don't form part of valid characters.

If the reason for wanting to do that is because you want `echo` to expand the `\n`, `\b`, `\0351`... escape sequences in the file (as UNIX conformant `echo` implementations do, [but not all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)), then [you'd rather use `printf` instead](/q/65803):

```
printf '%b\n' "$(cat my_file.txt)"
```

Contrary to `echo`, that one is portable and won't have problems if the content of the file starts with `-`.

---

As an alternative to `$(cat file)`, [with `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash`, one can also do: `$(<file)`](/a/368663). That's a special operator whereby the *shell* as opposed to `cat` reads the content of the  file to make up the expansion. It still strips the trailing newlines and chokes on NUL bytes except in `zsh`. In `bash`, that still forks an extra process. Also note that one difference is that you won't get any error if trying to read a file of type directory that way. Also, while `$(< file)` is special, `$(< file; other command)` is not (in `zsh`, when not emulating other shell, that would still expand the content of the `file`, by running the *implicit* `$READNULLCMD` command (typically a pager)).

Comment: But how to repeat standard input to standard output while interpreting special characters?

Comment: @NeilG This seems like a related but different question. If no other question on the site handles this, I would suggest you ask a brand new question about it, including example data.

Comment: I was thinking about it when I found the answer among those for this question @Kusalananda. Take a look.

Comment: @NeilG, well, just `printf '%b\n' "$(cat)"` or for more than once: `var=$(cat); printf '%b\n' "$var" "$var" "$var"...`, or use the `printf '%1$b\n%1$b...\n' "$(cat)"` supported by many `printf` implementations.

Comment: Lol, @StéphaneChazelas, thanks but I think I'll just stick with `| xargs echo -e`! GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release. But that's an interesting use of `cat`. I'll try some variations on that too.

Comment: @NeilG, as already noted, you can't use `xargs` unless you use the `-0` GNU extension as `xargs` mangles quotes, whitespaces **and backslash**. It will also fail for strings like `-nene` and for long strings as there's a limit (low on some systems) on the size of the arguments that can be passed to an external command.

Comment: Good to know @StéphaneChazelas . The command line length limit was what was bothering me most. I'm actually using `$(cat)` now too, as it's cooler and more conventional at the same time.

Answer (score 17):

Adding to other answers, you can also try input redirection instead of `cat`

```
echo "$(<my_file.txt)"
```

or

```
echo "`<my_file.txt`"
```

`$(...)` and `` `...` `` perform the same thing, i.e command substitution. It runs commands inside of it's scope and gives the output to the shell as if it was given as an input by the user. The only difference between these two is that `$(...)` can be nested simply and `` `...` `` needs to be escaped to be nested.

The quotes around command substitution preserve whitespaces

Comment: `\`...\`` can be recursive but with a much more awkward syntax. You must also watch out for backslashes inside them (even inside single quotes), and `"` if quoted. In any case with either syntax, they should be quoted when in list context unless you want split+glob to be applied to them. Note that `$(<file)` is a non-standard ksh extension (also available in bash and zsh)

Comment: Thank you! This is extremely helpful for debuging when your system SSD/HDD crashed and `cat` can't be loaded any more.

For example on a Raspberry Pi that browned out due to insufficent voltage `cat /sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:firmware/get_throttled` yields `bash: cat: command not found` But the shell built-in `echo \`</sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:firmware/get_throttled\`` still works and returns the desired debug code.

Answer (score 6):

As it was said,

> If you want `echo` to display the content of a file, you have to pass that content as an argument to `echo`

For instance, you can do it like this with `xargs` (considering that you need to enable interpretation of *backslash escapes*):

```
$ cat my_file.txt | xargs echo -e
```

Or simply what you've asked (whithout interpretation of *escapes sequences*):

```
$ cat my_file.txt | xargs echo
```

Comment: Note however that when using `xargs echo` (same as `xargs` btw as `echo` is the default command), it's the `echo` command from the file system that will be run, not the shell's builtin `echo` command. Also note that `xargs` expects its input in a very specific format (where blanks, newlines, quotes, backslashes have special meaning). `cat` doesn't make much sense here as there's only one file to concatenate (same as `< file.txt xargs echo`. Note that Unix compliant `echo`s do backslash escape expansion by default and output `-e` upon `echo -e`.

Comment: Of course! `xargs`! Yes! `command | command | command | xargs echo -e` will take the standard output of your command chain and pipe it to xargs which will then arrange it as parameters to echo which will print the special characters! Thank you!

Comment: @NeilG But note that `xargs` does special processing of quotes, and that not all external implementations of `echo` may have the non-standard `-e` option.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: you can't. `echo` (be it shell built-in or regular binary) doesn't process its standard input - it is one way only.

Comment: Question is, why would you actually want to do this?

Comment: please refer to multiple comments and text in the other answers to find out why.

Comment: Yes you can! Prefix `echo` with `xargs`! Well, I know, strictly you can't; but that has a similar effect that may solve some problem scenarios that need this behaviour.

Comment: @NeilG, with your suggestion `echo` still does not read from _stdin_. It's the `xargs` command reading _stdin_ and transcribing it to command line arguments that are passed to one or more instances of `echo`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @roaima (that's why I said "strictly you can't" and "similar effect").

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to redirection, it is important to note that Linux commands can interpret the argument you pass to them differently, thus leading to different behaviors. The crucial part is to understand that

- Some commands expect a path to a file and put the contents of that file within their STDIN. After that, such commands read from there, process it, and produce their output. For example, `cat` does so.
- Other commands put nothing within their STDIN and don't read from there. In other words, the STDIN is simply ignored. Instead, they directly read from theirs arguments and generate the output.

Therefore, some commands can depend entirely on what is within their STDIN, while others don't give a damn for what is there. That is important for redirection because if you redirect a STDOUT to the STDIN of a command that ignores it, you won't get the desired behavior.

If you run

```bash
cat
```

you will notice as if `cat` is hung, waiting for something. It happens because, if no content is passed to within the STDIN, the standard input is, by default, attached to the keyboard. In other words, `cat` is waiting us to type any content and send to it by pressing enter.

On the other hand,

```
echo
```

simply leaves the command because it doesn't reads from the STDIN. As it had no argument, there is nothing to the printed.

Therefore, if you type

```bash
echo < my_file.txt
```

Normally, `echo` would treat `my_file.txt` as an argument and would simply produce `my_file.txt` in the STDOUT, but `<` changes how `my_file.txt` is treated by the shell. Now, instead of passing `my_file.txt` as an argument to `echo`, the shell puts the content of `./my_file.txt` within the STDIN of `echo`. As we saw before, it doesn't print anything because `echo` doesn't read from the standard input.

If you really want that `echo` reads from STDIN, you must use `xargs`, that is,

```bash
xargs echo < my_file.txt
```

- `<` makes `my_file.txt` not an argument, but a path to a file whose content is put within STDIN.
- `xargs` runs the command given to it (`echo`) with the arguments read from STDIN.

Now it will prints out "Hello".

Similarly,

```bash
cat my_file.txt | xargs echo
```

also works:

- `cat` get the content of `./my_file.txt` and put it within its STDIN and print this content in its STDOUT.
- The pipe `|` takes the STDOUT of `cat` and put it within the STDIN of `echo` instead of printing this STDOUT on the terminal (the default behavior).
- `xargs` runs the command given to it (`echo`) with the arguments read from STDIN.

Comment: Note that both facts have been mentioned in other answers already (the fact that `echo` does not read its standard input, and that you can use `xargs`). Also note that `echo` happens to be the default utility that `xargs` executes (i.e, shorter: `xargs <my_file.txt`). There are also issues with using `xargs` that you don't mention, which includes the processing of quotes and whitespace.

Comment: @Kusalananda although these facts have been mentioned previously, none of answers here gave my solution (Stéphane has reached close it, though). That is right that the usage of `echo` is optional. I preferred to leave it for the sake of clarity. The issues concerning `xargs` are leave out since it is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: "xargs forces echo to read from the STDIN rather than its arguments." No, it doesn't. xargs itself reads stdin, parses the input and runs the command given with the input as arguments.

Comment: Also when you say none the answers have your solution, if you mean using xargs is the solution, it was already posted 7 years ago: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293231/70524

Comment: @muru "No, it doesn't." Corrected.

Comment: @muru "if you mean using xargs is the solution". No. The usage of `xargs`, pipes, etc has been done millions years ago. I obviously not saying that the other questions don't use them. I am saying that my solution, `xargs echo < my_file.txt`, cannot be found in the other answers, let alone my explanations concerning redirection.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, also the following should work:

```
echo `cat my_file.txt`
```

The part in backticks is replaced by the output of that command, i.e. in this case replaced by the file contents.

Comment: True, backticks work like `$( . . . )`. People who use `$()` usually prefer them because you can nest them. This question is old, though, it's much more satisfying to answer questions that are not already answered!

Comment: Not quite.  There is a subtle difference. When the back-tick form is used, a backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `, or \. The first back-tick not preceded by a backslash terminates the command.

When using the $(,,,) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command.

Comment: As that command substitution is not quoted, the split+glob operator would be applied to it. For instance if `my_file.txt` contains `*`, that would print the list of file names in the current directory.