# Encode file content and echo it as one line

Tags: bash, echo

I am trying to echo the content of key and certificate files encoded with base64 so that I can then copy the output into other places.

I found this thread: [Redirecting the content of a file to the command echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63658/redirecting-the-content-of-a-file-to-the-command-echo?newreg=c481bc0432304a3b830417155237575c) which shows how to echo the file content and also found ways to keep the newline characters for encoding. However when I add the `| base64` this breaks the output into multiple lines, and trying to add a second `echo` just replaces the newlines with white spaces.

```
$ echo "$(cat test.key)" | base64
LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCk1JSUpRZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRRUZB
QVNDQ1N3d2dna29BZ0VBQW9JQ0FRRFF4Tkh0aHZvcEp1Z0EKOHBsSUNUUU1pOGMwMzRERlR6Z1E5
ME5tcE5zN2hRczNQZ0QwU2JuSFcyVGxqTS9oM1F1QVE0Q1dqaHRiV1ZUbgpSREcveGxWRFBESVVV
MzB1UHJnK0N6dlhOUkhzQkE9PQotLS0tLUVORCBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCg==

$ echo $(echo "$(cat test.key)" | base64)
LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCk1JSUpRZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRRUZB QVNDQ1N3d2dna29BZ0VBQW9JQ0FRRFF4Tkh0aHZvcEp1Z0EKOHBsSUNUUU1pOGMwMzRERlR6Z1E5 ME5tcE5zN2hRczNQZ0QwU2JuSFcyVGxqTS9oM1F1QVE0Q1dqaHRiV1ZUbgpSREcveGxWRFBESVVV MzB1UHJnK0N6dlhOUkhzQkE9PQotLS0tLUVORCBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCg==
```

The desired output would be:

```
LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCk1JSUpRZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRRUZBQVNDQ1N3d2dna29BZ0VBQW9JQ0FRRFF4Tkh0aHZvcEp1Z0EKOHBsSUNUUU1pOGMwMzRERlR6Z1E5ME5tcE5zN2hRczNQZ0QwU2JuSFcyVGxqTS9oM1F1QVE0Q1dqaHRiV1ZUbgpSREcveGxWRFBESVVVMzB1UHJnK0N6dlhOUkhzQkE9PQotLS0tLUVORCBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCg==
```

How can I achieve this output?

Comment: [*Why does the base64 of a string contain “\n”?*](https://superuser.com/q/1225134/432690) and [*What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Comment: Also "useless use of `cat`". Consider `base64 -w 0 test.key` or `base64 -w 0 test.key; echo`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use the -w option (line wrapping) of base64 like this:

```
... | base64 -w 0
```

A value of 0 will disable line wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Not all versions of base64 support the `-w 0` flag (OSX), but the same effect of the `-w 0` option is created by using:

```
cat test.key | base64
```

The output can be used for gitlab variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, not all versions of base64 support `-w` flag (https://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/base64/).

That works for me:

```
base64 -e test.key | tr -d '\n\r'
```

Comment: You can tell echo to not add a new line to the end of the printed string:

echo -n "some_string" | base64

Comment: Yes, of course. But it's base64 that adds line breaks to the output.